# Combining multiple xml node values based on ID in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and got a requirement in project as mentioned below. I have a XML file as given below.

```html
<Results>
  - <Result>
    <Usuals>
      <Products>
        <Product>
        <ProductId>1</ProductId>
        <ProductName>Test1</ProductName>
        <ProductLocation>TestPlace1</ProductLocation>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>2</ProductId>
          <ProductName>Test2</ProductName>
          <ProductLocation>TestPlace2</ProductLocation>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>3</ProductId>
          <ProductName>Test3</ProductName>
          <ProductLocation>TestPlace3</ProductLocation>
        </Product>
      </Products>      
    </Usuals>
    </Result>

    - <Result>
      <Price>
        <Products>
          <Product>
            <ProductId>1</ProductId>
            <PriceValue>100</PriceValue>         
          </Product>
          <Product>
            <ProductId>2</ProductId>
            <PriceValue>200</PriceValue>
          </Product>
          <Product>
            <ProductId>3</ProductId>
            <PriceValue>300</PriceValue>
          </Product>
        </Products>
      </Price>
    </Result>
    
  <Result>
    <Items>
      <Products>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>1</ProductId>
          <ItemValue>400</ItemValue>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>2</ProductId>
          <ItemValue>500</ItemValue>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ProductId>3</ProductId>
          <ItemValue>600</ItemValue>
        </Product>
      </Products>
    </Items>
  </Result>
  </Results>
```

My goal is to produce the following pseudocode output using XSLT. I have tried from my side but couldn't find a way to achieve this. Can this be achieved?

```
foreach(Product product in Usuals.Products)
{
//display product.ProductId,
//display PriceValue for matching product.ProductId in Price.Products
//display ItemValue for matching product.ProductId in Items.Products
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for code.

Comment: "I have tried from my side" - what exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to define a *key*.  You can make do with just one key covering all the `Product` elements

```
<xsl:key name="productsById" match="Product" use="ProductId" />
```

Now given an ID `x` you can get a node set containing all the `Product` elements with that ID using the XPath expression

```
key('productsById', x)
```

This would give you a set of three element nodes, the matching `Product` elements from under `Usuals`, `Price` and `Items`, so the price would be accessible as

```
key('productsById', x)/PriceValue
```

and the `ItemValue` as

```
key('productsById', x)/ItemValue
```

(the fact that only one of the three `Product` elements returned by the `key` function has each of those children doesn't matter, the path expression will work correctly).

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply Ian. This is what I was looking for. Ian, I have a quick question here. Currently in the above xsl key, the value of "use" attribute is 'ProductId' which is a constant string across all the nodes. If different nodes have got different notations for 'ProductId', i.e if in above case 'Products' nodes under'Price' node  contain 'ProdId' instead of 'ProductId' and 'Products' nodes under "Items' node contain 'PID' instead of 'ProductId', I cannot use this approach right?. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @user3796454 In that case the simplest approach would be to use separate keys for the different sections - `<xsl:key name="priceProd" match="Price/Products/Product" use="ProdId" />` etc.